# Allow user to register using code in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

please I am trying to allow users to register with a coupon code, if coupon code is invalid dont register user, but when I tried it users are been registered even though the code is already used or invalid

I am using this package for the code https://github.com/michael-rubel/laravel-couponables

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'username' => $request->username,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);
        $user->redeemCoupon($request->code);
        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already registering the user before checking if the coupon is valid. Move this line after the validation.

```
$user->redeemCouponOr($request->code, function ($e) {
    //handle the different exceptions here if not valid.
});
$user = User::create([
            'username' => $request->username,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);
```

Or handle the validations inside the validator method

```
$request->validate([
            ...
            'code' =>'sometimes|exists:coupon_table,coupon_code_column,coupon_status_column,!used_or_some_other_status'
         ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom validation rule to verify code and check if the code is already used.

```
$redeemer->verifyCoupon($code);
$redeemer->isCouponAlreadyUsed($code);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that is not explained in the `Laravel Couponables`  package that you are using it clearly has explanations on the GitHub:

Listeners

> If you go event-driven, you can handle package events:
>
> CouponVerified
>
> CouponRedeemed
>
> CouponExpired
>
> CouponIsOverLimit
>
> CouponIsOverQuantity
>
> NotAllowedToRedeem
>
> FailedToRedeemCoupon

All the exceptions are well explained in the documentation

```
If something's going wrong, methods verifyCoupon and redeemCoupon will throw an exception:

CouponExpiredException      // Coupon is expired (`expires_at` column).
InvalidCouponException      // Coupon is not found in the database.
NotAllowedToRedeemException // Coupon is assigned to the specific model (`redeemer` morphs).
OverLimitException          // Coupon is over the limit for the specific model (`limit` column).
OverQuantityException       // Coupon is exhausted (`quantity` column).
CouponException
```

You can simply replace this line from your code:

```
$user->redeemCoupon($request->code);
```

To this:

```
$user->redeemCouponOr($request->code, function ($exception) {
    // Your action with $exception!
    print('This coupon is no longer valid'); //
});
```